# Align Edges of Element in HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several buttons which are displayed inline with `<h3>` tags. All `<h3>` tags are of equal length but still the edges of the buttons are not aligned.

I want to align the edges of buttons so that it looks plain.

Comment: show us the code to help you.. we can't guess it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your code looks like this:

```
<h3>hello</h3><input type="button" value="hello"></br>
<h3>hello 2</h3><input type="button" value="wad adwadaw a"></br>
<h3>hello 4</h3><input type="button" value="1231245 5"></br>
<h3>hello 55</h3><input type="button" value="asdasdddd"></br>
```

then the css should be:

```
h3{
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
input[type="button"]{
    width:300px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
h3{
    background:orange;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px

}
</style>
```

HTML

```
  <h3>Home</h3>
    <h3>About Us</h3>
    <h3>Contact</h3>
```

> You Should be Provide Screenshot or Code Sample for Getting Proper Answer.
>
> Note: Equal Edges with Same Length is not Possible if Button Content have not Same Width.

Comment: All Buttons should be aligned to the text